# Return nodes with only one specified relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a graph like this:
[image]

What i wanna do, is to return actors, which only played in one specified film.
So for example if I  pass an Iron Man 2 id, it should  return only Robert Downey. Scarlett Johansson is skipped because she has played in 3 films, and also she has a "IS_FRIEND_WITH" relationship.
This code which i wrote, return all the actors that played in film of `id 11 in this case`

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE ID(a) = 11
MATCH (b:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Movie)
RETURN b
```

If Iron Man 2 would be of Id = 11 it would return Scarlett and Robert Downey. I just want it to return only Robert Downey.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply another filter to select only nodes that have a single ACTED_IN relationship.

```
MATCH (a:Movie)
WHERE ID(a) = 11
MATCH (b:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]-(a)
// apply filter for nodes that have only a single ACTED_IN relationship
WITH b, size((b)-[:ACTED_IN]->()) as number_of_movies
WHERE number_of_movies = 1
RETURN b
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
WITH 11 AS movieId
MATCH (a:Actor)
WHERE [(a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) | id(m)] = [movieId]
RETURN a
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers you could do

```
MATCH (a:Movie)
WHERE ID(a) = 11
MATCH (b:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(a)
// Make sure there are no ACTED_IN relationships apart from the one to a
AND NOT (:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b)-[:ACTED_IN]->(a)
RETURN b
```

This might have a minor advantage in that it doesn't first collect all the `:ACTED_IN` relationships of the actor, but instead can quit the query as soon as it finds an additional relationship.

If you also want to remove the ones that have an `IS_FRIENDS_WITH` relationship then you can modify the query to

```
MATCH (a:Movie)
WHERE ID(a) = 11
MATCH (b:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(a)
// Make sure no other relationships exist
AND NOT ()<-[]-(b)-[:ACTED_IN]->(a)
RETURN b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:
we can specify the title of the movie to filter the query results,
then we use with to specify the variables that we will pass to the next part, among the variable we pass the number of movies which an actor acted in .
In the second part of the query we verify that the actor has acted only in the given movie.
Finally we collect these actors and return them as list along with the movie.

```
MATCH(a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie {title:'The Matrix'}) 
WITH size((a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)) AS uniqueMovieActor, m as theMovie 
MATCH() 
WHERE uniqueMovieActor = 1 
RETURN collect(DISTINCT actor) as uniqueMovieActors, theMovie
```